# C# how to "delete" first value of array, reorder array and set last value back at 0?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, datapoint

So I've got a `Datapoint[] = new Datapoint[50]` that I'm filling. As soon as the Datapoint array is full, how can I "delete" Datapoint[0] and set Datapoint[1] to Datapoint[0], Datapoint[2] to Datapoint[1]... etc. and make Datapoint[49] free again / to value 0/0?
I didn't had any success yet figuring it out since I don't wanna use a loop.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What about using a list? or a linked list? As for using the array, simply write a for-loop? `for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++) Datapoint[i] = Datapoint[i + 1]; Datapoint[49] = 0;`

Comment: @mjwills yes it solved my problem! add it as answer and i'm going to mark it as answer and upvote it! thanks sir.

Comment: If you do that operation a lot then an array is not the right data structure to use.

Comment: You say that you haven't figured it out. What have you tried so far?  (Hint: doing a repeated operation is usually done with a *loop*.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option to consider would be to create a completely new array and assign it to your existing variable.

The code would look something like:

```
existingVariableName = existingVariableName
    .Skip(1)
    .Concat(new Datapoint[] { new Datapoint() })
    .ToArray();
```

`Skip(1)` means to skip over the existing first element. `Concat` is used to add a new element at the end. `ToArray` materialises the LINQ query into the new resulting array.